# Integrating $f(x,y)=xy$ over parallelogram

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to integrate $f(x,y)=xy$ over a parallelogram with vertices $(-2,1)$, $(-1,3)$, $(1,3)$, $(0,1)$. My approach:$$\int \limits_{1}^{3}\int \limits_{\frac{1}{2}(y-5)}^{\frac{1}{2}(y-1)}xy\, \mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}y=-2$$ The solution says that it should be $-\frac{10}{3}$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I made the same error in computing the first integral I see. Sloppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can move $y$ into the outer integral:
$$I=\int_1^3y\int_{(y-5)/2}^{(y-1)/2}x\,dx\,dy$$
Then integrate the first integral:
$$=\frac12\int_1^3y[x^2]_{(y-5)/2}^{(y-1)/2}\,dy$$
$$=\frac18\int_1^3y((y-1)^2-(y-5)^2)\,dy$$
$$=\frac18\int_1^3y(8y-24)\,dy$$
$$=\int_1^3(y^2-3y)\,dy$$
The second follows:
$$=[y^3/3-3/2y^2]_1^3=-\frac{10}3$$

Comment: I spotted my mistake. Thanks.